# Can I set a breakpoint with gdb as I'm calling it?

Tags: gdb

I'm in the middle of a large debugging project, and every time I start running `gdb` I have to type `b 253`.

It would be really nice if I could set my run script so that `gdb` loads with that breakpoint already set.

To be more explicit: Here are the contents of `run.csh`:

```
gdb --args path/to/program arg1 arg2
```

Can I modify this so that, once I run it, I can just type `r` and the program breaks on line 253?

Comment: `run.csh`? You're writing scripts in csh? :-[

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. **Read [documentation of `gdb`](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/).**

You can [extend GDB](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Extending-GDB.html#Extending-GDB). You can have [Canned Sequences of Commands](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Sequences.html#Sequences).

You can define or use extensions in [Python](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Python.html#Python), in [Guile](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Guile.html#Guile). See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23970415/841108).

<sup>(you might need to recompile GDB itself from source, since sadly not all usual `gdb` are configured with Guile support)</sup>

You can have your `.gdbinit` file (read about [startup files](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Startup.html#index-gdb_002eini) and [command files](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Command-Files.html#Command-Files)). Btw you might prefer to `break` in function names, not in line numbers there. Read more about [specifying locations](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Specify-Location.html#Specify-Location).

Actually, many large projects have some `.gdbinit` (perhaps generated) in their source repository.

Be sure to use a recent version of GDB. The latest one (in March 2018) is [GDB 8.1](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/download/ANNOUNCEMENT)

Comment: `-x` and `-ex` look particularly relevant.