# Debugging struct with recursive pointers

Tags: rust, gdb

I have implemented a sort of tree structure for a filesystem thingy.

```
struct FileSystemNode{
    current_directory_path: String,
    current_directory_name: String,
    //we need mutable and immutable access to a node
    // (from here to child and from child's child to parent)
    parent_directory: Option<Rc<RefCell<FileSystemNode>>>,
    children: Vec<Rc<RefCell<FileSystemNode>>>,
    //if size is 0, this is a directory
    size: usize
}
```

I'm parsing a file that says which directories and files exist and then generate the new nodes on the fly and add them to my structure. Somewhere I have a bug, so now I want to debug this. Since IntelliJ community has no Rust debugger, I'm trying to use rust dgb.

Now when I have my root node created but it has no children, I can print the root node just fine:

```
$1 = Rc(strong=1, weak=0) = {value = RefCell(borrow=0) = {
    value = advent_of_code_2022::day7::FileSystemNode {
    current_directory_path: "/",
    current_directory_name: "", 
    parent_directory: core::option::Option<alloc::rc::Rc<core::cell::RefCell<advent_of_code_2022::day7::FileSystemNode>>>::none, 
    children: Vec(size=0), 
    size: 0},
    borrow = 0},
    strong = 1, weak = 0}
```

However, as soon as I add a second node and set the child / parent members accordingly, the print will try to follow all these parents and children (I assume), so there is a recursive call to print leading to an error in gdb I cannot even break. The following spams my gdb log:

> Python Exception <class 'RecursionError'>: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object

> Python Exception <class 'RecursionError'>: maximum recursion depth exceeded while getting the str of an object

Is there any way for me to prevent this recursion from taking place? Ideally for the `parent_directory` and `children` it would print just the `current_directory_path` or `current_directory_name` and `size` members, but for it would also help if it just gave me an address instead of following it or leaving it out altogether.

Here is a minimal working example, just build it, start in gdb, move to line `let node ...`, print root (it works) and then move to line `println!...", print root again, it spams the errors.

```
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::rc::Rc;

struct FileSystemNode{
    current_directory_path: String,
    current_directory_name: String,
    //we need mutable and immutable access to a node
    // (from here to child and from child's child to parent)
    parent_directory: Option<Rc<RefCell<FileSystemNode>>>,
    children: Vec<Rc<RefCell<FileSystemNode>>>,
    //if size is 0, this is a directory
    size: usize
}

impl FileSystemNode {
    pub fn new() -> FileSystemNode {
        return FileSystemNode {
            current_directory_path: String::from(""),
            current_directory_name: String::from(""),
            parent_directory: None,
            children: Vec::new(),
            size: 0
        };
    }
}

pub fn main(){
    let root = Rc::new(RefCell::new(FileSystemNode::new()));
    root.borrow_mut().current_directory_path = String::from("/");

    let node = Rc::new(RefCell::new(FileSystemNode::new()));
    node.borrow_mut().current_directory_path = String::from("/test/");
    node.borrow_mut().current_directory_name = String::from("test");
    node.borrow_mut().parent_directory = Some(Rc::clone(&root));

    root.borrow_mut().children.push(Rc::clone(&node));

    println!("");
}
```

Comment: not entirely sure if this counts as a dupe but does https://stackoverflow.com/a/23970415/12448530 answer your question?

Comment: If gdb really has no way of detecting recursions, then I fear that answer is the best I'll get. Though I had hoped for a smaller solution, where I don't have to learn and write pretty printers, then learn and write outputs for GraphViz on the fly. That's more work than the actual exercise I'm trying to solve. Either way, thanks for the hint.

Comment: What if you set a maximum depth when printing, like `p -max-depth 2 -- root`?

Comment: That seems to prevent the recursive error. Of course, now I can't really see the relations anymore, so I still need to write a pretty printer, I guess